# JScrollPane In JFrame with two panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I  want to add a scroll bar to my `JTextArea` but it just won't show up. I have read a lot of stuff on forums but all in vain. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```java
JPanel pan, pan2;
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
JTextField fname = new JTextField(18);
JLabel filename = new JLabel("Filename");
JButton view = new JButton("View");
public FileReading() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pan = new JPanel();
    pan2 = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
    //scroll.setBounds(400,400,400,400);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    text.setEditable(false);
    scroll.setViewportView(text);
    pan2.add(scroll);
    //scrollpane.setViewportView(text);
    pan2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //pan2.add(scrollpane);
    pan.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    pan.add(filename, FlowLayout.LEFT);
    pan.add(fname, FlowLayout.CENTER);
    pan.add(view, FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    view.addActionListener(this);
    fname.addActionListener(this);
    pan2.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pan2.add(pan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //BorderLayout.EAST
    //add(pan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(pan2);//, BorderLayout.CENTER
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileReading frame = new FileReading();
    frame.setTitle("Enter The Full Path to the File");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(400,400,400,400);
    //frame.setSize(400,400);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `scroll` (JScrollPane) to the `pan2` not to the `text` (JTextArea)
try this

```
pan2.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

in place of `pan2.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

**EDIT**

`JTextArea` gets added automatically when we add `JScrollPane` into the panel, as you have added `text` (JTextArea) inside `JScrollPane`

here -> `JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);`

Comment: thanks alot you guys, i had a hard time figuring that out. now its all awesomely working the way i wanted it to work :).

Comment: @user1825142 if it worked ... you can accept the answer and upvote also

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
add(scroll);//, BorderLayout.CENTER
add(pan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

instead of

```
add(pan2);//, BorderLayout.CENTER
```

This way we are directly adding the scrollpane to main frame and putting other things below